# Conditionally change colors of individual bars in bar chart in Excel VB based on range

Tags: vba, excel, formatting, conditional-statements

I am working on an Excel project and am trying to format the colors of a bar chart (and later a pie chart by the same reasoning) in order to display `RED`, `GREEN`, or `YELLOW` based on another range of data. The data range is...

**Sheet**: `Overview`

**Range**: `E15:E36`

These values are percentages. Based on what percentage it falls between, I'd like the bars to be formatted green, red or yellow.

If between 100 - 90, Green
If between 89 - 70, Yellow
If between 69 - 1, Red

Below is my code to this point (for the bar chart):

```
    Sub Macro2()
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
        ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Overview").Range("A15:A36")
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Overview").Range("A15:A36,B15:B36")
        ActiveChart.ApplyLayout (2)
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
        ActiveChart.Legend.Select
        Selection.Delete
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Rating Site Distribution"
    End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm not at all familiar with VBA and feel entirely out of my element on this one...

Also, would the same function work for a pie chart to define the color by the same parameters?

Thank in advance!!

Comment: See this link by Jon (http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/conditional-formatting-of-excel-charts/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response ... I've seen this, but I don't believe this will work with a dynamic data set... I would have to re-arrange the groupings each time the data changed. I'd prefer a dynamic solution that uses the specified range to determine color... Thanks!

Comment: @Ben currently doing a tidy of my questions and answers: did my attempt answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

here a vba function I use to invert negative bars so they are red. Maybe this can be adapted:

The function is called from a sub routine in the a module in the workbook like this:

```
Sub FixTheGraph()
  FormatGraph("Overview")
End Sub
```

Here's the Function. You can just paste it below the sub-routine:

```
Function FormatGraph(myWorksheet As String)

Excel.Sheets(myWorksheet).Select

Dim myChartObject As ChartObject
For Each myChartObject In Excel.ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    myChartObject.Select

    Dim myPoint As Integer, valArray

    With Excel.ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
        valArray = .Values
        For myPoint = 1 To .Points.Count
            'myVal = valArray(myPoint)
            Select Case valArray(myPoint)
                Case 0.9 To 1
                    With .Points(myPoint)
                        .Interior.ColorIndex = 1 '<change colour to suit
                    End With
                Case 0.7 To 0.9
                    With .Points(myPoint)
                        .Interior.ColorIndex = 5 '<change colour to suit
                    End With
                Case Is < 0.7
                    With .Points(myPoint)
                        .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    End With
                End Select
        Next
    End With

Next myChartObject
Excel.Sheets(myWorksheet).Cells(1, 1).Select

End Function
```

Comment: I'm in the process of trying to adapt it right now... I'll post back when I get somewhere... thanks for trying to help!

Comment: No love so far... I'll keep trying to integrate this somehow but I may end up just putting it on Freelancer and putting a bounty on it. I am truly out of my element with VBA. It's not a high priority at the moment, but I appreciate your help!

Comment: ok - how out of your depth? do you know how to set up the code module and where to paste this Function?

Comment: I've editied my original post a bit but I really need to test it in xl - can't remember what the colorIndexes are ....we need to change the bits that says Excel.xlAutomatic

Comment: just tested latest above vba and worked on the little test graph

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is a chart type xlBarStacked. Then give it three series - one for each color.

In each series, if the element value is in range, use the value, otherwise set the series.Value element to 0.

Since your ranges are mutually exclusive, each bar will have only one color.